# To integrate websphere commerce with third party currency converting website?

Tags: web-services, websphere-commerce

How to integrate a WebSphere commerce application with third party website currency converter, the currency converter website return a wsdl file. How can I work, any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods.

Method 1.  Overload the payment calculation CommandTask to call out the WSDL OR create a new CommandTask to call out the WSDL and append it to the Command process (latter is better because it doesn't change current process flow).

Method 2.  Populate the currency table in WCS using WCS scheduled jobs.

Of the two and not knowing your requirements.... Method 2 has better performance because it is relatively static and WCS will automatically dynacache it.

See the process flow at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rgxxref.htm

See the ERD at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.data.doc/refs/rdmindex.htm

See the API at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/overview-summary.html

In all situations, I would recommend that you apply for the WCS business partner program.  http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/websphere-commerce/technology-partners/.   Once you join IBM, they'll assign staff to provision an environment for you and help you with the 3rd party integration and maybe even publish a white paper together.